# Split a list of strings with an unknown number of parts and return them as table

Tags: sql-server

I need to parse a string by slash signs in sql. the values I have is like this:

```
0041/PH 5PC0000001/WCHTKSKHDS0/D
```

and I want to have like 0041 in one column and in second column I want to have PH 5PC0000001 and in third column WCHTKSKHDS0 and so on. But, slashes are not constant, in some rows they are more and in some the are less for example: like this

```
PH/HCGA/002878//HTJ/, 0004/PH 5DI0000001/LTRKARDR/M /L.
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Ugh you have a messy bunch of data to work with here. First you will have to parse these delimited values into rows. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings Then you will have to create a dynamic pivot to put the data back into a dynamic number of columns.

Comment: @SeanLange, I think it's not that complicated...

Comment: @Shnugo actually it is. You did the split using XML but the final number of columns is dynamic.

Comment: @SeanLange, yes, you are right of course. As we don't know the maximum number of parts, this might be a problem. But I'd assume, that there is a max number one could "hard code"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @inpTbl TABLE(inpString VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @inpTbl VALUES ('0041/PH 5PC0000001/WCHTKSKHDS0/D')
                          ,('PH/HCGA/002878//HTJ/')
                          ,('0004/PH 5DI0000001/LTRKARDR/M /L');

WITH ConvertToXMLLikeStrings AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(inpString,'/','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) AS MyData
    FROM @inpTbl AS it
)
SELECT MyData.value('x[1]','varchar(max)') AS Val1
      ,MyData.value('x[2]','varchar(max)') AS Val2
      ,MyData.value('x[3]','varchar(max)') AS Val3
      ,MyData.value('x[4]','varchar(max)') AS Val4
      ,MyData.value('x[5]','varchar(max)') AS Val5
      ,MyData.value('x[6]','varchar(max)') AS Val6
      --add as many as you need
FROM ConvertToXMLLikeStrings;
```

The result

```
Val1    Val2                Val3        Val4    Val5    Val6
0041    PH      5PC0000001  WCHTKSKHDS0 D       NULL    NULL
PH      HCGA                002878              HTJ 
0004    PH      5DI0000001  LTRKARDR    M       L       NULL
```

Comment: This works great until there is a need for a Val7. This is why I stated it needs to be dynamic here. Regardless this gets a +1 as a solid example of splitting the delimited values.

Comment: Is there any function which I can use to parse, so I don't have to put manually instead it parse out the string in whole column automatically?

Comment: @Mr.Singh Please explain what you want... It is very easy to pack this approach either in a VIEW or in an inline TVF. If you need help, please let me know, if this is solved, please tick the acceptance check below the vote counter, thx

Comment: I have like over thousand rows of different strings and I can't put all those into one @inpTbl. Is there any other way where we can use some kind of loop or function where I just put the column name and then that function or loop which parse the string?

Comment: @Mr.Singh, No, you do not have to put anything into a `@inpTbl`. This is just to show a test case. You do not have to do more than to start with the `;WITH Convert...` (set a semicolon right before) and change the `@inpTbl` within the `WITH` to your actual table's name and the `inpString` to the column name which holds these values...